# Loading .rcproject from iOS local directory

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, augmented-reality, realitykit

I am trying to load a `rcproject` from a local directory. My target is, to load it from an URL and then show it.

If I load it like this:

```swift
let modelScene =  try? Entity.loadAnchor(named: "Experience")
```

everything works fine.

But if I do this:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "./Experience")
```

or

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "./Experience.rcproject")
```

and

```
let modelScene =  try? Entity.loadAnchor(contentsOf: url, withName: "Experience")
```

or

```
let modelScene =  try? Entity.loadAnchor(contentsOf: url)
```

I get the following error:

```
// [Pipeline] Failed to open scene 'Experience -- file:///'.
```

I have no idea, what the issue here is. Did someone has an idea, what i can try?

My development target is 14.4

In the apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/entity/stored_entities/loading_entities_from_a_file), they write, that it should work like this, right?

Comment: I also tried the `.reality` format, it had the same result

Comment: Ok, i got it to run with the `.reality` files. :-) I missed to add it to the compiled resources, but if i used loadAnchor it worked. why? no clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadAnchor(contentsOf:withName:)` type method was composed for `.usd`, `.usda`, `.usdc`, `.usdz` and `.reality` file formats. However official documentation says that now they work only for **Reality files**. You can read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/entity/stored_entities/loading_entities_from_a_file).

```
public static func loadAnchor(contentsOf url: URL, 
                       withName resourceName: String?) throws -> AnchorEntity
```

And here's a definition inside your code:

> Supported file formats are USD or Reality. In order to identify a resource across a network session, the resource needs to have a unique name. This name is set using `resourceName`. All participants in the network session need to load the resource and assign the same `resourceName`.